# Error when using imellipse to create mask

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I try to create mask on a image, however I get the following error:

> Undefined function 'createMask' for input arguments of type
>   'matlab.graphics.primitive.Image'.

I can't figure out what's wrong. Any help? Thanks in advance!

```
img = imread('pout.tif');
figure, h_im = imshow(img);
h = imellipse;
position = wait(h);
BW = createMask(position,h_im);
```

Comment: what were you trying to do with `position = wait(h);`? Anyway, if you wanted to create a mask by dragging an ellipse on the image, you can just delete the `wait` line and replace the last line with `BW = createMask(h,h_im);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

If I understand correctly, you are trying to get an ellipse input from the user and obtaining a mask of it.
There are two changes which needs to be done:

1. The wait function is not needed, since imellipse function waits until the user provide an ellipse.
2. First argument of createMask should be the ellipse h.

**Updated code**

```
img = imread('pout.tif');
figure, h_im = imshow(img);
h = imellipse;
BW = createMask(h,h_im);
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: This solved my problem! It seem I messed up on the line `position = wait(h);
`.Thanks for clearing me up!